# Is it possible to use Adafruit's Circuit Playground Express's 2MB storage in Arduino IDE?

Tags: adafruit

I understand that the extra 2MB of memory is for circuit python.  However, I wouldn't mind having access to 2MB of storage and using the Arduino IDE/low level C to access it.  Is that possible?  If so, how?

Comment: please provide all available information in your post ... there is no reason why people would have to do internet searches for a datasheet and for any applicable libraries before being able to answer your question

Comment: You may be interested in Adafruit's FRAM breakout board: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1895 They have an SPI version too, and both support 256Kbit's of persistent storage. Plus, they're super easy to use.

Comment: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SPIFlash

Comment: What is Adafruit's Circuit Playground Express's 2MB storage?

Comment: @Majenko, a board by Adafruit a well known and established company with a good web site. Circuit Playground Express is the only one not Arduino board in Arduino SAMD boards package. you could ask what is Neopixels or Feather Huzzah or MKR

Comment: @Juraj Yes.... I know who Adafruit are. But what *is* the "2MB storage"? Is it a physical device? If so what is it? Or is it some online service provided by Adafruit? It's not clear, and I shouldn't need to google these things.

Comment: So... it's just a run-of-the-mill 16Mb SPI flash chip. Big whoop. Wanna fight about it? Also Cypress list that model as obsolete now...

Comment: @Majenko, as I saw the question I opened the Adafruit site for the board and there it is: "2 MB of SPI Flash storage, used primarily with CircuitPython to store code and libraries.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In their [guided tour](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-circuit-playground-express/guided-tour) of the Adafruit Circuit Playground Express, it specifically states:

> You can use this in Arduino or CircuitPython to store files.

So yes, it is possible. As far as the how, according to [this guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-express-designed-for-circuit-python-circuitpython/using-spi-flash) (also from Adafruit), that they have also made a library, [Adafruit SPI Flash](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SPIFlash), which has a bunch of examples showing how to read from, write to, and format the SPI flash whilst retaining compatibility with CircuitPython, among other things.